# Fill out and center content in tabularx

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

**Problem:**

I am using the IEEE template for conference papers and do not manage to fill out the right part of a table in a way that makes the table look centered.

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author 1}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Affiliation} \\
City, Country \\
E-mail}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author 2}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Affiliation}\\
City, Country \\
E-mail}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext[1]
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
keywords
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Chapter 1}
\blindtext
\section{Chapter 2}
\blindtext
\section{Chapter 3}
\blindtext
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Caption text here}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Main headline for countries}}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Country 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Country 2}} \\
\midrule
Description Country 1 & \# & Description Country 2 & \# \\
\midrule
text & 12 & text text text & 11 \\
text text text & 11 & text text text & 9 \\
text text & 10 & text text & 8 \\
text text & 8 & text text text & 8 \\
text text text & 7 & text text & 5 \\
text text text & 6 & text text & 1 \\
text text text & 1 & text text text text & 1 \\
text text & 1 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**CLS file for IEEE is available here (was too big to include here):**

https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/conferences/Conference-LaTeX-template_7-9-18.zip

**Current output:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

To fill out/center the content inside the table in a way that it does not leave space on the right side of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It have no sense a tabular**x** table without any `X` column.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cccc}
```

Simply change that line by

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{{\centering}Xc>{\centering}Xc}
```

And you have exactly what you want, but IMHO it could better do not center the text columns:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XcXc}
```

> [image: mwe]

I also will change the seconc \midrule by:

```
\cmidrule(rl){1-2}\cmidrule(rl){3-4}
```

or maybe increase `\tabcolsep` and/or insert a third empty column:

```
%\tabcolsep1em
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}XccXc@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Main headline for countries}}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Country 1}} && \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Country 2}} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-2}\cmidrule(l){4-5}
Description Country 1 & \# && Description Country 2 & \# \\
\midrule
text           & 12 &&  text text text & 11 \\
...
```

> [image: mwe]